# Character not displaying in html

Tags: java, encoding, character

I am having trouble displaying the "velar nasal" character (ŋ)(but I assume the same problem would arise with other rare characters).

I have a MySQL table which contains a word with this character.
When my code retrieves it to display in my HTML page, it is displayed as a question mark.

I have tried a number of things:
1) Tried using MySQL's CONVERT to convert the retrieved string to UTF-8 because I understood that the string is stored in my table as "Latin1":

```
SELECT CONVERT(Name USING utf8)
```

Instead of:

```
SELECT Name
```

This did not help, and, when I saved a string in my java code with the problematic word ("Yolŋu"), and then passed the String through the rest of the code the problem still occured (ie: The problem does not lie in the different character encoding that my DB uses).

2) I also tried creating a new String from bytes:

```
new String(name.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

The String is being passed from java to the html via a JSONObject that is passed to a javascript file:

Relevant JSON code:

```
JSONArray names = new JSONArray();
        for (int iD: iDs)
        {
            JSONObject namesData = new JSONObject();
            String name = NameDB.getNameName(iD);
            nameData.put("label", name);
            nameData.put("value", iD);
            names.put(nameData);
        }
        return names;
```

Relevant servlet code:

```
response.setContentType("application/json");

        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) 
        {
            out.print(namesJSONArray);
        }
```

Relevant js code:

An ajax call to the servlet is made via jquery ui's autocomplete "source" option.

I am pretty new to coding in general and very new to the character encoding topic.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, in Java String should already hold correct Unicode, so `new String(string.getBytes(...), ...)` is a hack, with its own troubles.

***1. The database***

It would be nice if the database held the text in UTF-8. The encoding can be set on database, table and column level. The first thing is to investigate *how* the text is stored. A table dump (mysqldump) would be least error prone.

If you can use UTF-8, this must be set form MySQL on the database engine, and for data transfer for the java driver.

In every case you can check a round-trip in java JDBC by filling a table field, and reading it again, as also reading that existing troublesome field.

Dump the code points of the string.

```
String dump(String s) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); ) {
        int cp = s.codePointAt(i);
        if (32 < cp && cp < 128) {
            sb.append((char) cp);
        } else {
            sb.append("U+").append(Integer.toHexString(cp));
        }
        sb.append(' ');
        i += Character.charCount(cp);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

***2. The output***

Here probably lies the error. Call at the beginning:

```
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
... response.getWriter(); // Now converts java's Unicode text to UTF-8.
```

For HTML a charset specification is in order too. Especially when the HTML page is saved to the file system, the encoding header would be lost.

Comment: Great. Point number (2) did the trick. Small correction: the method is called "setCharacterEncoding".

Comment: Corrected for other visitors.

Answer (score 0):

You should be assure about the following things:

1. Your JVM must work with `file.encoding=UTF-8` param
2. Your mySQL table in which contains special characters must be parametrized with `encoding=UTF-8`
3. Your web UI should specify the meta tag with the encoding you have saved the web page in your editor, so UTF-8

If the problem persists, try to use `HTML entities` `(&entity)` instead.